# Wordpress admin after login shows "Could not retrieve data" error

Tags: wordpress, admin

Yesterday I was working on a WordPress site, and it was perfectly working. And now today when I logged in through login details the blank page is appearing with this error:

> Could not retrieve data.

I don't know what's wrong in that, suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Anything in your Apache/PHP logs? What does the error look like? What did you recently change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always take the usual steps :

Deactivate all plugins to see if one of them is causing the problem (you can do that by removing their folders from the wp-content/plugins directory).

You can also check your server logs, it might give you information, maybe a database connection problem ?

Comment: thank you so much sir.. it worked.. It just happened because of the one plugin.. I have removed that plugin.. I guess whatever errors comes after installing the theme, it all because of the plugins only... thanks for your suggestion..